# Add multiple filters columns at where conditions in MongoDB filters

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using **C#** **.Net 4.5** and **MongoDB 2.0.**

I want to add multiple columns at where conditions in **`MongoDB`**  filters.

I added two columns at where conditions such as **`"Address"`** and **`"CompanyName"`** which returns proper result.

```
    string conString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    MongoClient Client = new MongoClient(conString);
    IMongoDatabase DB = Client.GetDatabase("Sample");
    IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("customers");
    FilterDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument> builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
    FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filters = builder.Eq("Address", "xxxx") & builder.Eq("CompanyName", "xxxx");
    List<BsonDocument> list = await collection.Find(filters).ToListAsync();
    foreach (var doc in list)
        Console.Write(doc);
```

But, I add more than two columns as filters such as **`"Address"`** ,**`"CompanyName"`** and **`"ContactName"`**.It's not working.I added three columns but its only took two columns.How to I add more than two columns as filters in **`MongoDB`** in **`C#`**.

```
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filters = builder.Eq("Address", "XXX") & builder.Eq("CompanyName", "XXXX") & builder.Eq("ContactName", "XXXX");
```

Comment: Why have you started using `And` instead of `Eq` on the builder?

Comment: @KevinSmith sorry I make mistake.I modified.But not working.

Comment: Do you have an example of an expected matching document?

Comment: @KevinSmith,Thanks Its working properly.